# How convert two separate objects from separate arrays into one string?

Tags: c#

```
string[] groups;
int groupCount;
double[] grades;
int gradeCount;
```

So the `groups` and `grades` are in two separate arrays and I need to combine them as *one* `string` and add them to a new array.

```
string[] test = new string[groupCount];
for (int i = 0; i < groupCount; i++)
{
   test[i] = ("{0}:   {1}", groups[i], Math.Round(grades[i],2));              
   Console.WriteLine("{0}", test[i]);
}
```

How do i do it ?

Comment: Yeah it throws a lot of errors ;
It expects ";" so it would be declared propperly;

also : 

Error 1 Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement

Comment: please have a look at [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot `string.Format()`

It should be,

```
string.Format("{0}:   {1}", groups[i], Math.Round(grades[i], 2));
```

Hope helps,

Comment: OMG ! Lifesaver :D Thank you very much ! !!

Answer (score 3):

C# 6.0 *string interpolation* (please, notice `$` before the string):

```
test[i] = $"{groups[i]}:   {Math.Round(grades[i],2)}";
```

Another possibility is *Linq* (in order to output the *entire* collection in *one go*):

```
string[] groups;
double[] grades;

...

var test = groups
  .Zip(grades, (group, grade) => $"{group}:    {Math.Round(grade, 2)}")
  .ToArray(); // array materialization (if you want just to output you don't need it)

Console.Write(String.Join(Environemnt.NewLine, test));
```

Comment: Got my vote for interpolation. I always prefer answers with more up-to-date solutions. For more info, one can refer to: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/24/c-sharp-6-0-features/49/string-interpolation#t=201610111152547586484